# Bootstrap 4 Columns Not Adjusting As Expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a 4 column bootstrap responsive grid.

xs works fine, col-xs-12, as the 4 columns change to be 4 single rows.
lg works fine, col-lg-3, 4 columns across the page, each 1/4 of the page.

When I start reducing the size of the page for md and sm that I have my problem.

when I hit md I hoped to get two rows with 2 column, col-md-6. At the first responsive layout change as I reduce the size of the window I get column 1 and 2 in the first row as expected, column 3 is in a new 2nd row in the first column, as expected, but the 4th column is in a new 3rd row in the first column.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block visible-sm-block visible-md-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <p>Some text</p>              
    </div>
</div>
```

All help will be most appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have so many clearfixes? Remove them and your layout will look fine.

Comment: @Rachel S, to be clear, did you want me to remove just the clearfix class from the 3 divs where it was defined or also remove the visible-*-block classes as well. I only removed the clearfix and still did not get as expected in the md size, roughly 900px -> 1100px. AT that size columns 1 and 2 displayed as expected, column 3 was in row 2 but in second column not in first and the fourth column was in row 3, column 1.

Comment: okay, problem fixed after trial and error but I think I now have a better understanding of the clearfix and visible-*-block classes.  I removed all clearfix and visible-*-block classes and then added a clearfix and visible-md-block before the 3rd column. This now displays at all sizes as expected.  Thanks for the direction in getting this solved.

Comment: Your code worked without any clearfix divs at all, just with the row and columns divs.

Answer (score 0):

you have used  for the first column and  for remaining columns.

Use only  for all the columns that resolves the issue.

block will use complete width for div so if you use block for sm or md it will lose the responsiveness.

Comment: I have removed all clearfix and block classes and attempted to add only where required.  I am still only having issue at md level.  Adding visible-md-block before 3rd only, 4th only, 3rd and 4th, still gives me the 3 rows as described in my comment above.

Comment: visible-md-block still uses complete width. you need to avoid using block for all rows.